# how to get these stuff into linq in C#?

Tags: c#, linq

i have a problem with linq, i have the following code:

```
        Models.Users user = null;
        foreach (var item in db.Users)
        {
            if (item.username.Equals(username))
            {
                ausgabe = true;
                user = item;
            }
        }

        // linq, does not work
        user = null;
        var test = from u in db.Users
                   where u.username.Equals(username)
                   select u;
        user = (Models.Users)test;
```

at the runtime i get a error because test i IQueryable, but how to make this conversation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the problem is **casting** a query to a user, when you want to *execute* the query, so probably:

```
user = test.SingleOrDefault();
```

(see also `FirstOrDefault()`, `First()`, and `Single()`)

Also, for convenience and readability, can I suggest:

```
where u.username == username
```

(which also, in *regular* code, avoids the problem of `u.username` being `null`, and thus causing a `NullReferenceException`)

Comment: where can i set a default value?

Comment: @gurehbgui and what would the "default value" of a class look like? Better to just check whether `user == null` after the query, and do what you want. Or possible: `user = test.SingleOrDefault() ?? EmptyUser;`

Answer (score 2):

Your cast is wrong, you want assign a list of objects to one object:

```
   var test = from u in db.Users
               where u.username.Equals(username)
               select u;
    user = (Models.Users)test; // wrong part.
```

Do

```
user = test.FirstOrDefault();
```

Or

```
 user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.username.Equals(username));
```

Comment: where can i set a default value?

Comment: The default part means in your case it would be null if no user name was found

Comment: @gurehbgui, I just see your comment, but Kev comment is complete.